# How to concatenate one element with other across rows in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, concatenation, cell-array

i had a cell array **C** of dimension 64x8 in which each row is comprised of the following dimension,

Say,

```
10x26 double    10x26 double    10x26 double    10x26 double    10x26 double    10x26 double    10x26 double    10x26 double
```

i used the following command to convert each element of the cell array to a matrix,

```
D = cellfun(@(x) {x(:)}, C);
```

which gave me the following output,

```
260x1 double    260x1 double    260x1 double    260x1 double    260x1 double    260x1 double    260x1 double    260x1 double
```

Now, i need to  horizontally concatenate each **260x1** element across the 8 rows of the cell array, so i would get a

> 2080x1 dimension-ed value in a single cell

where 2080 is the product of 260x8 (along 8 rows). and this should transform the **64x8** Cell array to **64x1** array.

So i must get the output like the below,

```
2080x1
2080x1
......
......
......
2080x1
```

I hope `cellfun` cannot be used since it applies the functions to each element of the cell array. but i need to concatenate the elements of cell array itself, also let me know if there is a way to do it without loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html):

```
array = vertcat(cellArray{:});
```

The `{:}` part returns the contents of all cells as a list of outputs, and `vertcat` takes these as inputs and concatenates them along the first dimension. If you wanted to concatenate along the second dimension you can use [`horzcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html), and if you wanted to concatenate along some other dimension you can use the general [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html).

`horzcat(A, B, ...)` and `vertcat(A, B, ...)` are the functional forms of the syntax `[A, B, ...]` and `[A; B; ...]`, respectively.

Note you could also have used these functions on your original `C` without using `cellfun` as you did. Experiment with these methods to better understand their functionality.